# Extracting data from large text file using Python

Tags: python, full-text-search, bigdata, extract, whoosh

For a project, I need to extract data from different sources. One of these sources is a large (.txt) file (~750 Mb). I've tried the common parsing techniques, but the file is too large and it takes too much time. A solution I found here, is to build a full-text index by using the Whoosh library. I'm new to python, and new to full-text search. Do you have any idea of how to open the file in a reasonable time and how to design a schema? My file has the following structure

---

*FIELD* NO

% something that I want to extract %

*FIELD* NOT-INTERESTING

% something not interesting %

*FIELD* TP

% something I want to extract %

Comment: You can use find with grep on linux. Or try reading line by line instead of reading the complete file at once

Comment: @Stack , re.search and re.findall exist you know that?

Comment: @SkillerDz there are lots of ways, the man issue is reading such a big file all at once

Comment: @Stack , you can use multiprocessing too for Upgrade the Speed of the running of the script or Cython too

Comment: @Stack there are a lot of ways to Upgrade the Running time , for mathematiques we use numpy example

Comment: @SkillerDz true. we can use multiple ways to increase the speed.

Comment: @Stack , the Power Of Multi-Threading can be better found on Multi-Proccesing , Because the multiprocess Module Create Threads and Will Use Multi Processors for Increase the Speed

Answer (score 0):

for UP the speed of the Script , we will use multiprocessing,
for extract a data, you should use re.findall or re.search , but on this script i will use re.search

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import re

def find():
   f = open('data.txt', 'r').readlines()
   for n in f:
     word = n.rstrip()
     f = re.seach(r'%(.*)%', word)
     field = f.group(1)
     print field


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    p = Process(target=find())
    p.start()
```